# В Yii 1.x навесить hook на проверку прав доступа к действию контролера?

Tags: php, yii, controller, hook, action

Возможно ли в **Yii 1.x** навесить свой hook именно на проверку прав доступа к действию контролера?

К примеру, у нас есть некий контролер:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'roles'=>array('root', 'admin', 'manager'),
            ),
            array('allow', 
                'actions'=>array('send', 'list'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

так вот мне нужно выполнять свой код, только для запросов, требующих **определенных прав доступа** (всё действия, кроме: send и list), при этом **не реагировать на случаи когда такие права не требуются** (действия: send и list).
При этом внимание: мне нужно выполнять код, до проверки прав доступа к действию!

Возможно ли и как?

Answer (score 0):

Переопределите в контроллере метод, отвечающий за это:

```
public function filterAccessControl($filterChain)
{
    // Your code is here
    parent::filterAccessControl($filterChain);
}
```

Comment: а как в этом методе проверить что для выполнения текущего действия контролера требуются определенные права пользователя, т.е. авторизация?

Comment: Не очень понятно то, чего вы хотите достичь. Если поконкретней опишете необходимые действия, то возможно это вообще реализуется по другому.

Comment: У меня есть мобильное приложение (HTML5), которое взаимодействует с сайтом на Yii. Приложение посылает Ajax-запросы Yii-сайту, тот отвечает контентом. Некоторые запросы должны быть авторизованы. К сожалению мобильное приложение на HTML5 не поддерживает работу COOKIE, потому никаких сессий. Авторизация приложения построена на базе передачи им token'а. Производить авторизацию по токену для каждого запроса я не хочу. Думаю сделать разделение: чтобы авторизация по токену производилась только для действий контролера требующих авторизацию.